# Are women obligated in the positive commandment of remission on Shemitta?

Tags: halacha, women, transactions, shmita, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, Jews are supposed to remit the debts of other Jews every 7 years during the Shemitta year, which has a [positive commandment](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Positive_Mitzvot.141) and a [negative commandment](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Negative_Mitzvot.230) (*aseh sheba* and *lav sheba*). My question is, are women also obligated in the positive commandment, or since it is time bound are they Petur?

Comment: @Kirk thanks for clarifying. I hope you approve of my edit. Perhaps it might be good to make this question more general? Why specifically shmita remission?

Comment: Seemingly, the same logic that applies to kiddush and matza applies here. You can't be obligated in just one half of the same mitzva.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sefer HaChinuch (477)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaChinukh.477.6?lang=bi) writes that the positive *mitzvah* of cancelling loans in *shemittah* applies to males and females.

Comment: To fill this in a bit more, as DoubleAA's comment indicated: if a "yes-do" and "don't-do" are tied together, women have to do both. "Don't work on Shabbos, yes honor the day." "Don't eat Chametz, yes eat Matza." This one's even clearer-cut: "Yes relinquish the loan, don't attempt to collect it."

Comment: @Shalom The logic seems like it can't be pecced but yet the gemara doesn't give it as an example. Do you have a source that allows extending the logic to any such case?

Comment: @DoubleAA I would admit, no I don't. Though as you'd stated, you'd have to split hairs in some very odd ways to find someone who is "not pressing" the loan, yet failing to "relinquish" it. (Except perhaps being yotzei *dvar hashmitah* in how you describe your cancellation...)